# Wordpress site only half loaded

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a call from a customer who's Wordpress site is not working and I started taking a look at but I cannot understand what's going on there.

On the same server (only another directory) there are other wordpress setups running and they are working perfectly fine. So that's the first part that is kind of ... interesting.

When I logg in to the WP-Admin and access the page again it loads without any problems. Everything is displayed correctly. Same if I add a PHP GET-Parameter like ?anythinginteresting.

In the apache error logs I only find "PHP Notices" - nothing I would worry about.

Any hints? I'm going out of ideas right now...

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: I agree. Will focus on that in my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a caching issue as mentioned by @michealrmcneill it comes from the WP-Super-Cache Plugin. This plugin is not "knocked out" when disabled in WP-Admin it needs to be deleted in /wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/* to be removed. Addionally there are two files: wp-content/advanced-cache.php and /wp-content/plugins/wp-cache-config.php that are related to the plugin.